# Ensuring all Django views return 200?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have lots of simple Django views that look like this:

```
@team_leader_required
def view_all_teams(request):
    teams = Team.objects.all()

    template_vars = {'toolbar': 'teams',
                     'teams': teams}
    return render(request, "all_teams.html", template_vars)
```

I end up writing lots of unit tests of the form:

```
def test_view_all_teams_renders(self):
    user = self.create_team_leader()
    self.log_in(user)

    response = self.client.get(reverse('all_teams'))
    self.assertHttp200(response)
```

Despite my convenience methods for creating users (e.g. `.create_team_leader`) and various convenience assertions (e.g. `.assertHttp200`), I still end up with a lot of duplication in my tests.

(My tests are simple since I can't see anything else useful to assert about these views -- `TestCase.assertTemplateUsed` breaks if you rename templates, even if the view is correct.)

It's easy to miss a test, which gives me little confidence when I rename templates. Is there any way I can automatically generate test cases? Something like (psuedo-code):

```
for every view in urls:
    if view doesn't take extra arguments:
        test that view returns 200 when a logged in superuser does a GET
```

**EDIT**

Here's a representative snippet from my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^teams/$', 'teams.views.view_all_teams', name='all_teams'),
    url(r'^teams/major/$', 'teams.views.view_major_teams', name='major_teams'),
    url(r'^teams/minor/$', 'teams.views.view_minor_teams', name='minor_teams'),
    url(r'^teams/(?P<team_id>\d+)/$', 'teams.views.view_team', name='view_team'),
    url(r'^teams/(?P<team_id>\d+)/edit$', 'teams.views.edit_team', name='edit_team'),
    url(r'^teams/(?P<team_id>\d+)/delete$', 'teams.views.delete_team', name='delete_team'),
```

I'd like to automatically test the first three views in this list.

Comment: This requires knowing more about your url patterns. Do they all have names (like `all_teams`)? Maybe you could give a small reproducible example of `urls.urlpatterns` for the module you're testing?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I've added an example, let me know if I can clarify further.

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.test import TestCase


class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_simple_views(self):
        url_names = [
            'all_teams',
            'major_teams',
            'minor_teams',
            'view_team',
            'edit_team',
        ]

        user = self.create_team_leader()
        self.log_in(user)

        for url_name in url_names:
            try:
                url = urlresolvers.reverse(url_name, args=(), kwargs={})
            except urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch:
                #print('Pass {}'.format(url_name))
                continue

            #print('Try {}'.format(url_name))
            response = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertHttp200(response)
```

If all url patterns have their name, You can use follow code to define `url_names`:

```
url_names = [p.name for p in teams.urls.urlpatterns]
```

**Known Issues**

- If view function fail, you will not know which view failed.
- Views next to failed view will not be tested.

### Another version that handle above issues.

```
import unittest

from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.test import TestCase

from teams.urls import urlpatterns


class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    ...

    def setUp(self):
        user = self.create_team_leader()
        self.log_in(user)

    url_names = [p.name for p in urlpatterns]
    vs = vars()
    def make_test_function(idx, url_name, url):
        def  t(self):
            response = self.client.get(url)
            self.assertHttp200(response)
        t.__name__ = 'test_' + idx
        t.__doc__ = 'simple get test for ' + url_name
        return t

    for i, url_name in enumerate(url_names):
        i = str(i)
        try:
            url = urlresolvers.reverse(url_name, args=(), kwargs={})
            vs['test_' + i] = make_test_function(i, url_name, url)
        except urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch as e:
            vs['test_' + i] = unittest.skip(url_name + ' requires parameter(s) or view not found')(lambda: 0)

    del url_names, vs, make_test_function,
```